# How to pass socket.io instance to typegraphql resolver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, typegraphql

I need to emit an event to room clients from typegraphql resolver. I tried to `modules.export = io` in index.js, but it creates a new instance, not the same. And, in result, it doesn't work

Comment: You're going to have to share some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More likely you need to share a bit more code to know for sure , but this is something I did very often, something like :

```
// io.index.js

// setup io first 

const io = require("socket.io")();
// or
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server();

// then export it

module.exports = io;
```

then just use it in another file like

```
// someotherfile.js

const io = require('./io.index.js');
io.emit("an event sent to all connected clients");

// or
io.to("room").emit("an event sent to all connected clients in room");
```

This way it's always the same instance of io.